# Insert Cursor fails to write results to table

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, cursor

Insert Cursor fails to write results to table. The Search Cursor is returning the results, but errors when trying to insert into field.

```
# Insert Cursor for GDB table to GDB table  
# Import modules, environment settings
import arcpy, traceback, string
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Database connection variables on SPGISPROC1
OutFGDB = r"P:\batch\APO\District_overlay.gdb\pa_fp_dat1"
InFGDB = r"P:\batch\APO\District_overlay.gdb\pa_fp_rel1"

#Create cursor for input table items
InCursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(InFGDB)

# Create a variable that stores the value for column in a given row of the input table

for InRow in InCursor:

    parcel      = InRow.getValue('pafp_frq_PARCEL')  
    fp_zone1    = InRow.getValue('pafp_frq_ZONE2') 

    # Copy the stored value from the input table into the output table
    gdbCursor = arcpy.InsertCursor(OutFGDB)
    row = gdbCursor.newRow()

    if fp_zone1:
        fp_zone1 = fp_zone1.upper

    #Fill out fields with variables from input table        
    row.pafp_frq_PARCEL = parcel
    row.pafp_frq_ZONE2  = fp_zone1    

    #Insert new row into output file 
    gdbCursor.insertRow(row)

#Delete cursor and row objects to remove locks on the data 
del row
del cursor
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 325, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\gisdata\Python\Insert_table_Cursor.py", line 28, in <module>
    row.pafp_frq_PARCEL = parcel
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\_base.py", line 35, in __setattr__
    return setattr(self._arc_object, attr, ao)
RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
```

Comment: Typically, this message comes up when you are trying to insert a value into a field that does not exist or if you are trying to insert a value that is the incorrect data type for the field.

Comment: You might also try moving the creation of the `InsertCursor` outside the `for` loop.  Because you create the `InsertCursor` within the `for` loop, you are actually creating multiple `InsertCursor`'s which may be creating locks on your dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing I would do is to create your insert cursor outside of your `for` loop iterating on your search cursor; you are unnecessarily creating your insert cursor for each feature in `InFGDB`. And with respect to that insert cursor, you are not deleting it after each iteration which is likely why you are not seeing the new rows.

Second, and this is totally stylistic, but I would recommend using some better variable names to help keep things straight.

Here's how I'd write it:

```
# Insert Cursor for GDB table to GDB table  
# Import modules, environment settings
import arcpy, traceback, string
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Database connection variables on SPGISPROC1
outFC = r"P:\batch\APO\District_overlay.gdb\pa_fp_dat1"
inFC = r"P:\batch\APO\District_overlay.gdb\pa_fp_rel1"

#Create cursor for input table items
sCur = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inFC,['pafp_frq_PARCEL','pafp_frq_ZONE2']) # make sure the field names in the list correspond to your input featureclass
iCur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outFC,['pafp_frq_PARCEL','pafp_frq_ZONE2']) # make sure the field names in the list correspond to your output featureclass

for sRow in sCur:
    # I think the arcpy row object behaves differently than other tuples so we have to explicitly assign each value in the row to our new variables
    # parcel,fp_zone1 = sRow
    parcel = sRow[0]  
    fp_zone1 = sRow[1]
    if fp_zone1 is not None:
        try: fp_zone1 = fp_zone1.upper
        except: pass

    # Copy the stored value from the input table into the output table
    iCur.insertRow((parcel,fp_zone1))

del sCur,iCur
```

If this still fails, we can do some more testing to ensure the appropriate fields exist in your target featureclass.

Comment: Also would be a good idea to convert the cursors to da cursors and to restrict the cursor fields for both the search and insert cursors to just the two relevant fields. Performance will be dramatically better.

Comment: @blord-castillo yes, definitely would suggest that as well if he's running 10.1.

Comment: Yep, must be 10.1. He is using 10.1 according to the traceback.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I have incorprated Jasons changes to the Code, However we are still getting the error code.  What changes could be made to use the da cursors?

Comment: To go with @Brians suggestion, verify that the fields you are trying to populate in the new rows exist, are of the right type, and are spelled correctly.

Comment: I've edited the code in my answer to use the data access cursors of `arcpy`.

Comment: OK we are getting closer.  I have check the Input table fields and values and they are the same.  However we have a new error after incorporating Jason's changes to the code                                                          File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 325, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\gisdata\Python\Insert_table_Cursor2.py", line 21, in <module>
    newrow = iCur.newRow()
AttributeError: 'da.InsertCursor' object has no attribute 'newRow'

Comment: Here is the new Error:    File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 325, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\gisdata\Python\Insert_table_Cursor2.py", line 21, in <module>
    newrow = iCur.newRow()
AttributeError: 'da.InsertCursor' object has no attribute 'newRow'

Comment: I updated the code to use the correct method for the `arcpy.da.InsertCursor()`. The new-style cursors don't use the `newRow()` object, they merely append a list (or tuple) of values in sequence to a new row using the `insertRow()` method.  This should work for you now.

Comment: Jason,  see my edits of the code field names above. Here is the latest error code:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 325, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\gisdata\Python\Insert_table_Cursor2.py", line 21, in <module>
    iCur.insertRow((parcel,fp_zone1))
TypeError: value #1 - unsupported type: builtin_function_or_method
>>>

Comment: It sounds like my single-line casting of values from the row object is not compatible with the way the `arcpy` row object works. I changed `parcel,fp_zone1 = sRow` back into the individual variable assignments we had before. Also see my comments regarding field names when creating the cursor objects.

Comment: Jason,  This error seems to be pointing problems with the insert fields which are 'parcel and fp_zone1 of type text. which is why I changed them in them pior to yout latest revison. I Apprecate your help and patiance with this problem. raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 325, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\gisdata\Python\Insert_table_Cursor2.py", line 24, in <module>
    iCur.insertRow((parcel,fp_zone1))
RuntimeError: Cannot find field 'pafp_frq_PARCEL'

Comment: I think that error is pretty straightforward: Cannot find field 'pafp_frq_PARCEL'